# Can I make a Google ad display conditionally?

Tags: javascript, adsense

I have a sort of "freemium" model on my web site, so that if a user is subscribed, they don't see the Google Adsense ad that I have on the page.

So I'd like to make the Adsense ad displa or not depending on a conditional `if()` statement in my Javasript code.

However, the code one gets from Google is designed to be inserted directly into the HTML, and more than that, they are doing some tricky stuff involving having some variables set within a comment area, which I can't get my head around.

This is what the code looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "xx-xxx-00000000000000000000";
/* karamoh */
google_ad_slot = "0000000000";
google_ad_width = 320;
google_ad_height = 50;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

Is it possible to convert this in such a way so that I can wrap an `if()` statement around it?

*(I suppose I could put it all in a `document.write()` function, but that seems so unelegant. Surely there's a way that utilizes the Javascript more directly?)*

Answer (score 2):

Cleanest way to do it is to check server-side if your client is premium or not and simply do not insert tag in page sent to client at all.

If you don't have access to it for some reason and don't mind extra request to show_ads.js, it seems that setting a non-sensical `google_ad_client` makes Adsense service to reply with 400 and not draw any ad at all, so you can use this instead of very first line of ad tag:

```
if(premiumClient)
    google_ad_client = "some-nonsense-value"
else
    google_ad_client = "your-correct-value"
end
```

Also testing shows that if you output `<script>` tag with `document.write` it blocks execution just like it really was in document, so either what you yourself suggested or, a little less intrusive following code might work too:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "xx-xxx-00000000000000000000";
/* karamoh */
google_ad_slot = "0000000000";
google_ad_width = 320;
google_ad_height = 50;
//-->
if(!premiumUser)
    document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"><'+'/script>')
</script>
```

I can't remember though if it is indeed guaranteed anywhere that it really will block rest of execution, so, because of another `document.write` in show_ads.js it might fail right now in some browsers or suddenly start failing in future.

Comment: I like your second suggestion because even though it means leaving in a little more code than I hoped, there's probably less wait time for a premium user if I don't make the call to Google for the 400 reply.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems after some experimentation that these methods do not work. I have been in touch with Google support, and they have told me that I need to hard code in their Adsense code or it will not work. Have you by change implemented either of the above suggestions and got them to work? I just ask because if you have, then maybe I could press the issue further with Google support.

Answer (score 1):

How about something along the lines of :

```
if(userIsNotSubscribed)
    document.getElementById("advertisementDiv").innerHTML = advertisement;
    // Where advertisement = The Code given to you by Google
```

Comment: Will likely fail because show_ads.js called from ad tag uses document.write and it tends to not play nicely with really dynamic DOM access.

Comment: How about JSONP? Does even that trigger issues?